# Detecting Allelic Imbalance

Tags: python

I am interested in detecting allelic imbalance for a credible set of SNPs. Currently, I am looking for some packages, hopefully, for Python, that can assist with this. I am aware of this R package, https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.13/bioc/html/AllelicImbalance.html, but I am hoping someone knows of a similar Python library.

Cheers

Comment: You're comparing availability on Bioconductor to availability on Python. BioC is specializing on biological software, which Python does not (or at least doesn't have an equivalent community).

Comment: Why not just use R? Jumping between that and python is the norm.

Comment: What do you mean by "allelic imbalance". This maybe a term used in RNAseq because everyone seems to understand it, but this is not  a term used in population genetics.

Comment: @RamRS, I am more familiar with Python, and dont have alot of experience with R. With that being said, I should probably familiarize myself with R going forward.

Comment: It's not about the language itself, @Krizbomb. Python doesn't have a BioC equivalent, AFAIK.

Comment: Hi @RamRS, Yes I know that there is not a python equivalent, thanks anyways.